# Informix PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, informix

We have an older version (I think its 9) of informix running on our server that is the backend db for a vendor software. I have an ODBC for it to ms access but now they want to do powerbi stuff. Im finding the odbc is throwing error on certain tables and given that its vendor software, they're less inclined to upgrade the version. Everything I've seen seems to show that Informix doesn't like slaves that aren't informix and cloud isn't an option. Any suggestions for getting this data on a different db other than pulling csv files?

Comment: Version 9 of Informix was last released circa 2005 — and that would have been a late bug-fix release.  There aren't going to be many options for transferring the data to another DBMS other than unloading the data.  Informix 9 doesn't have CSV support — you'll likely get Informix UNLOAD format with pipe delimited fields.  That can be converted to CSV if need so be.  (I have `unl2csv` and `csv2unl` Perl scripts that do the job, for example — see my profile to contact me by email, and include the SO question URL in the email and Informix in the title, please.)